# QML application style

Tags: qt, qml

I'm writing an application for tablet using QML.

The main QML file of the application is something like this:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow
    visible: true
    title: "MyApp"

    menuBar: MenuBar {
        Menu {
            title: qsTr("File")
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("Open project")
            }
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("Exit")
                onTriggered: Qt.quit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I run the app on an Android device, the menu is styled like a standard Android menu, that is a button (with the "3 points" icon) on the top right corner. This is very good.

Instead if I run the app on a Windows device, the menu is like a standard desktop application menu (the traditional file menu...). This style is not suitable for a tablet application.

There is a way to choose the style of the application?
Thanks!

Comment: After lots of struggle with stock QML components the solution I found was "don't use stock QML components"

Answer (score 3):

The correct style should be [picked up by default](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols.git/tree/src/controls/Private/qquickcontrolsettings.cpp). If it's not, it means that a style for that device type (e.g. touch) isn't available. If you want to use a specific style, you can set the `QT_QUICK_CONTROLS_STYLE` environment variable before running your application. However, some styles can only be run on the platform they are built for. For example, the Android style needs a [specific file from a directory on the device](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols.git/tree/src/controls/Styles/Android/qquickandroidstyle.cpp) in order to function properly.

Note that Qt Quick Controls have a stronger focus on desktop. If you have the opportunity, and you *do not* need a native style, I'd recommend trying out [Qt Labs Controls](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.6/qtlabscontrols-index.html). They are more touch-oriented, and have a [style that implements Microsoft's Universal Design Guidelines](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.6/qtlabscontrols-universal.html).

[image]

They currently have [three different styles](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/qtlabscontrols-styles.html) available, and any style can be used on any platform.

Comment: I've tried to set QT_QUICK_CONTROLS_STYLE to Android style under Windows, but the menu doesn't appear at all :( . Maybe I will try Qt Labs Controls, but I have to upgrade Qt (I'm using 5.5)

Comment: Using the Android style on Windows won't work; please see my first edit.

Answer (score 2):

Without styling, components from Qt Quick Controls are supposed have a *native* look. You can make your own styles for [almost all of them](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-controls-styles-qmlmodule.html), though.